# MySQL converting enum values to integer values

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, enums

I have a table which includes an ENUM field with values 'B', 'N', 'F', and 'V'. I would like to assign each of these letters a weight:

```
B: -2
N: -1
F: 1
V: 2
```

These weights should appear in a column in a select statement. Finally, I want to add these values together. Is this possible?

The goal is to do this in django, but using MySQL will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
select sum(case enum_field
                when 'B' then -2
                when 'N' then -1
                when 'F' then 1
                when 'V' then 2   
           end) as total_sum
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when enum_field = 'B' then -2
                when enum_field = 'N' then -1
                when enum_field = 'F' then 1
                when enum_field = 'V' then 2   
           end) as total_sum
from your_table
```